# No access when using putty ssh between windows 7 and cubietruck embedded board with debian 8.7

Tags: windows-7, ssh, putty, debian-jessie

I have a windows 7 laptop and cubietruck board with Mainline 4.9.7 Debian Jessie (based on debian 8.7) and I need to achieve an ssh connection between them via a wireless router.On cubietruck I have installed opnssh-client and openssh-server and have checked that it listens to port 22. On windows I try with putty to connect to board via ssh. The connection is done , I give username and password but then it freezes and I cannot access any of the folders of the debian.
I also tried the mobaxterm but the same result. Does anyone has an idea of what I have done wrong?

Comment: It would probably be good to check log files for anything openssh-server or authentication services might be logging there (and include any findings in your question).

Comment: @zagrimsan I gave systemctl status sshd and show on log the line
Accepted password for user from the ip and port of the windows system and then session opened for user by (uid=0). Where else should I check?

Comment: It sounds like the sshd part of things goes ok, but it might be that there's something that hangs during the login session start-up. Use `journalctl -l --since="5 minutes ago"` to peek into all logged things related to the SSH login (adjust the `since` parameter value as needed). You should see there `systemd` starting up a session, at least, but maybe there are also some errors that could explain what goes wrong.